# Getting a "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'", without even using the '<' character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check if a condition is true, of which all the parts are integers and I am not using any '<' signs, but still I get this error. I am really confused...

Code:

```
import sys

packets, packets_x, packets_y, packets_z = [], [], [], []

for packet in sys.stdin:
    if packet == "\n":
        break
    packets.append(packet[:-1])
    packets_x.append(int(list(packet.split())[0]))
    packets_y.append(int(list(packet.split())[1]))
    packets_z.append(int(list(packet.split())[2]))

while True:
    for number in range(len(packets)):
        if int(sorted(packets_x)[0]) == packets_x[number] and int(sorted(packets_y)[0]) == packets_y[number] and int(sorted(packets_z)[0]) == packets_z[number]:
            print(packets[number])
            packets[number] = "a"
            packets_x[number] = "a"
            packets_y[number] = "a"
            packets_y[number] = "a"

    if packets.count("a") == len(packets) + 1:
        break
```

Input I used:

```
6220    1   10  Because he's the hero Gotham deserves, 
6210    1   10  Asd
<ENTER>
```

`<ENTER>` - Click enter, don't actually type that.
Type the inputs line by line, don't type them all at once.

Error I get:

```
if int(sorted(packets_x)[0]) == packets_x[number] and int(sorted(packets_y)[0]) == packets_y[number] and int(sorted(packets_z)[0]) == packets_z[number]:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Could this be some kind of a Python error?

Comment: Hint: try `sorted([1, "a string"])` at the Python prompt and see what happens.

Comment: You don't use `<`, but `sorted()` does.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks! I didn't know that you can't use numbers and strings together.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Could you answer it so that you earn the points for giving the answer? I don't want to take your credit.

Comment: @NemPlayer: I don't have time for a proper answer right now, unfortunately. I'll happily upvote your answer (or someone else's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if-statement doesn't use the '<' sign, but the `sorted()` function does!

I am getting the error because the `sorted()` function can't sort different types of variables.

If we try `sorted([1, "a string"])`, you will get the error, but if we try `sorted([5, 2])`, it will work.

This solution was written based on Mark Dickinson's and Barmar's comments.

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be in Python3, but not in Python2.7
And the solution for python3 can be:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,'bla',4,5,None]
```

Python2.7:

```
>>> sorted(a)
[None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'bla']
```

Python3:

```
>>> sorted(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Can be fixed with:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: str(x))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None, 'bla']
```